# how to remove white space to the right of flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox to create a responsive layout of a product list page but this code leaves a lot of whitespace to the right of the page, ive tried using justify-content:space-between but that did not work as well. Adding overflow:hidden to .container class did nothing as well.

edit:someone said it works fine on their end but this is how
[my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kbcM.png) looks

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .2s linear;
} 

body{
    overflow-x: hidden;  
} 

.container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 40px 0;  

}

.card{
    height:500px;
    width:280px ;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    align-self: center;
    margin: 40px;
}

.card img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card .info
  {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
  }

.card .info .stars i
{
     color: gold;
     padding: 10px 0;

}

.card .info .price{
    font-size: 20px;
    color:#f00333;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.card .info h3{
    color: #333;
    padding-top: 5px;

}

.card .discount
{
    position: absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    display: grid;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;


}

.card .panel
{
    position: absolute;
    top:15px;
    right: -50%;
    width: 45px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.644);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: column;

}

.card:hover .panel{
    right: 15px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.card button
{
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    bottom: 0%;
    height: 40px;
    width: 140px;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: .2s;
}

.card:hover button{
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 25%;
}

.card button:hover{
    background: (255,0,0,0.6);
}

.card .panel a{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.card .panel a:hover{
    color: rgba(255,0,0,0.9);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
<div class="container">

  <div class="card">
      <img src="assets/women1.jpeg" alt="">
      <span class="discount">-20%</span>
      <div class="panel">
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-heart"></a>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-share"></a>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-search"></a>
      </div>
      <a href="#"><button>add to cart</button></a>
      <div class="info">

          <h3>women's clothing</h3>
          <div class="stars">
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star-half"></i>
          </div>
          <strong class="price">$100/-</strong>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
      <img src="assets/women1.jpeg" alt="">
      <span class="discount">-20%</span>
      <div class="panel">
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-heart"></a>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-share"></a>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-search"></a>
      </div>
      <a href="#"><button>add to cart</button></a>
      <div class="info">

          <h3>women's clothing</h3>
          <div class="stars">
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star-half"></i>
          </div>
          <strong class="price">$100/-</strong>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
      <img src="assets/women1.jpeg" alt="">
      <span class="discount">-20%</span>
      <div class="panel">
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-heart"></a>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-share"></a>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-search"></a>
      </div>
      <a href="#"><button>add to cart</button></a>
      <div class="info">

          <h3>women's clothing</h3>
          <div class="stars">
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star-half"></i>
          </div>
          <strong class="price">$100/-</strong>
      </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

It Works Fine.
In Your Browser do a hard refresh.
I hope it will do the job done.

Hard Refresh : `Ctrl + F5`

Click [here](https://www.documate.org/automation/what-is-a-hard-refresh-how-to-do-a-hard-refresh-in-any-browser/). It are some docs on hard Refresh If you want to know more.

Or If Nothing Works use `position : absolute` or `Bootstrap`.